# AML run.log() and run.log_list() fail without error

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a Pipeline with DatabricksSteps each containing:

```
from azureml.core.run import Run
run = Run.get_context()
#do stuff
run.log(name, val, desc)
run.log_list(name, vals, desc)
run.log_image(title, fig, desc)
```

Only `log_image()` seems to work.  The image appears in the "images" section of the AML experiment workspace as expected, but the "tracked metrics" and "charts" areas are blank.  In an interactive job, `run.log()` and `run.log_list()` work as expected.  I tested that there is no problem with the arguments by using `print()` instead of `run.log()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add run.flush() at the end of the script.